# Mathjax Offline app error

Tags: android, mathjax

Hello i am trying to implement mathjax offline, i referred to this on github https://github.com/leathrum/android-apps,Can anyone help with this why this is not working???
i have tried from every sample i could get online,currently when in other application it works for online when i add

```
  <html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\"></script><link href=\"main.css\"type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" /></head><body>
```

Tried this thing...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private String doubleEscapeTeX(String s)
    {
        String s1 = "";
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            if (i >= s.length())
            {
                return s1;
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) == '\'')
            {
                StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                s1 = stringbuffer.append(s1).append('\\').toString();
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) != '\n')
            {
                StringBuffer stringbuffer1 = new StringBuffer();
                s1 = stringbuffer1.append(s1).append(s.charAt(i)).toString();
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) == '\\')
            {
                StringBuffer stringbuffer2 = new StringBuffer();
                s1 = stringbuffer2.append(s1).append("\\").toString();
            }
            i++;
        } while (true);
    }

    private int exampleIndex = 0;

    private String getExample(int index) {
        return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tex_examples)[index];
    }



    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer stringbuffer1 = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer stringbuffer2 = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer stringbuffer3 = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer stringbuffer4 = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer stringbuffer5 = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer stringbuffer6 = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer stringbuffer7 = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer stringbuffer8 = new StringBuffer();
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar", stringbuffer.append(stringbuffer1.append(stringbuffer2.append(stringbuffer3.append(stringbuffer4.append(stringbuffer5.append(stringbuffer6.append(stringbuffer7.append(stringbuffer8.append("<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>").append("MathJax.Hub.Config({ ").toString()).append("showMathMenu: false, ").toString()).append("jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], ").toString()).append("extensions: ['tex2jax.js'], ").toString()).append("TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js','noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] } ").toString()).append("});</script>").toString()).append("<script type='text/javascript' ").toString()).append("src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'").toString()).append("></script><span id='math'></span>").toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
        EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        edittext.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        edittext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        edittext.setText("");
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button2)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button3)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button4)).setOnClickListener(this);
        TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview3);
        textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(textview.getText().toString()));
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.button2))
        {
            WebView webview2 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
            EditText edittext1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
            StringBuffer stringbuffer2 = new StringBuffer();
            StringBuffer stringbuffer3 = new StringBuffer();
            webview2.loadUrl(stringbuffer2.append(stringbuffer3.append("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\[").append(doubleEscapeTeX(edittext1.getText().toString())).toString()).append("\\\\]';").toString());
            webview2.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
        } else
        {
            if (view == findViewById(R.id.button3))
            {
                WebView webview1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit)).setText("");
                webview1.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='';");
                webview1.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
                return;
            }
            if (view == findViewById(R.id.button4))
            {
                WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
                EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
                int i = exampleIndex;
                exampleIndex = i + 1;
                edittext.setText(getExample(i));
                if (exampleIndex > -1 + getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tex_examples).length)
                {
                    exampleIndex = 0;
                }
                StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                StringBuffer stringbuffer1 = new StringBuffer();
                webview.loadUrl(stringbuffer.append(stringbuffer1.append("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\[").append(doubleEscapeTeX(edittext.getText().toString())).toString()).append("\\\\]';").toString());
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

getting error like this

```
   E/AndroidProtocolHandler(26612): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js
   I/chromium(26612): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
   I/chromium(26612): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
   D/dalvikvm(26612): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 92K, 12% free 9425K/10596K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
   I/chromium(26612): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)

   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", source: http://bar/ (1)
   I/chromium(27592): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined", source: http://bar/ (1)
```

Comment: What you getting as error?

Comment: There are two main way that MathJax get all the files it needs: from the Content Delivery Network (CDN) which require being online, or by downloading onto your local machine, which you can use while offline. Before trying with java try using something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>` with the correct path for your local install. See http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html for how to download and the following page for how to configure.

Comment: did you find a solution @nayana ? im too stuck with this problem.

Comment: Yes I got the solution,uploading answer

Answer (score 0):

No need to use StringBuffer,just try to add following lines

```
 WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    w.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                          +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ " 
                            +"showMathMenu: false, "
                            +"jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], " // output/SVG
                            +"extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'], " 
                            +"TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                              +"'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, "
                          +"});</script>"
                          +"<script type='text/javascript' "
                          +"src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
                          +"></script>"
                          +"<script type='text/javascript'>getLiteralMML = function() {"
                          +"math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
                          +"mml=math.root.toMathML(''); return mml;"
                          +"}; getEscapedMML = function() {"
                          +"math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
                          +"mml=math.root.toMathMLquote(getLiteralMML()); return mml;}"
                          +"</script>"
                          +"<span id='math'></span><pre><span id='mmlout'></span></pre>","text/html","utf-8","");
    w.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() { public void clipMML(String s) {
                WebView ww = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
                android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clipboard.setText(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MathML copied to clipboard",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }}, "injectedObject");
```